# Error on Xcode: Expected method to write array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have another arrays problem...

I have declared an array as follows:

```
NSArray *sliderValAtTimes;
```

This is the code with the error:
Code:`sliderValAtTimes[x] = sliderValue;`

Error: Expected method to write array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

Declarations:

```
int x = 0;
sliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.slider.value];
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NSArray` is immutable. You can't replace an element of an `NSArray`. You need an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like that format made the error go away.